# Application Loader Codesign Problems

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, app-store-connect, codesign

I sign and package my apps with the PackageApplication script from the Xcode developer tools 4.2. When I validate the generated app bundle from the generated .ipa file, it says that everything is valid.

```
$ codesign --verify -vvv MyApp.app/
MyApp.app/: valid on disk
MyApp.app/: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

So that looks good. And when I show the infos of the signature it looks well too.

```
$ codesign --display -vvv MyApp.app/
enter code hereExecutable=/Users/user/Desktop/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier=com.example.MyApp
Format=bundle with Mach-O universal (armv6 armv7)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=8870 flags=0x0(none) hashes=435+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=e8fc1bf220542a49cf249a302df5d59fee8c7170
Signature size=4312
Authority=iPhone Distribution: My Name
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Oct 20, 2011 11:31:25 AM
Info.plist entries=37
Sealed Resources rules=3 files=1109
Internal requirements count=1 size=620
```

But as soon as I try to upload that app with the Application Loader, it says

> Application failed code sign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

Now I'm completely lost! The codesign utility tells me that everything is ok, but the Application Loader tells me that the signature is not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea what was wrong. But creating new profiles and deleting all old profiles did the job.